# jquery is this a valid http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, httprequest

I have this http request

```
GET /deals/couchbaseDocument/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "amenities" : "Maids "
        }
    }
}
```

when i put it in **curl**, it gives me results, i want to build a web app to call that request.

what i did is removing the newlines and put the whole text in **.getjson()**

as this:

```
var query = $("#query").val();
        query = query.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        $.getJSON(query, function (results) {
            alert("success");
            alert(results);
        })
        .success(function () { alert(" second success"); })
        .error(function () {
            alert("error");
            alert(query);
        });
```

i kept getting the error alert, i wonder if what i did is actually what should it be done to send that request

#### I read this

I found that .getJson could be like this:

```
$.getJSON('httpURL',
       { parameter1: "parameter value", parameter2: "parameter value" })
```

i wonder if i should pass my **json request** as a parameter

in case of the whole picture** i am working on **sense elasticsearch** plugin

Comment: @Drakes in your case, i didn't get the error message, but i didn't get any alert, though i have alerts in all parts

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of jQuery's getJson, you can pass a javascript object ([jQuery.getJSON() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)) so you can do something like this

```
var queryData = {
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "amenities" : "Maids "
        }
    }
};
$.getJSON('httpURL', queryData)
```

Comment: are you saying that the `httpURL` would be ` /deals/couchbaseDocument/_search` and the other data will be the `queryData` ?

Comment: Yes. Replace `httpURL` with your real url. The `queryData` needs to be a javascript object and not a string so if you're reading the values from a textbox you'll need to use `JSON.parse(jsonString);` to convert it into a javascript object.

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: could you please give me a code to get the url and the queryData from my string please?

Comment: Sorry but I believe that it is up to you how to do that :)
(and StackOverflow is not a place to write code with that purpose)